# How to turn/ lead the purest and most strong willed people to the dark side or evil path?

Tags: science-based, magic, science-fiction, psychology, urban-fantasy

How can I turn the purest and most strong willed good people to the dark side or evil path? For example the main characters *Natsu* and *Naruto* from the animes *Fairy Tail* and *Naruto*, they are one of the strongest will and purest people with a high sense of justice. So it's hard or nigh impossible to turn them evil.

In my story my main character is an evil/villain protagonist from a magic science world. There my MC is a highly intellectual scientist and a little overpowered. There are some people with a high sense of justice with strong willed people. I want to break their will and turn them into sadistic killers or just cold blooded killers without remorse for killing people, regardless of age and gender, but without damaging their personalities or something like that. But I don't know how to turn them evil, so I want some tips or ideas how to do that.

Comment: You should add information about the characters you are referencing as not everybody has seen these animes.

Comment: What is evil in this context? Most killers aren't sadist. One could argue our special forces are cold blooded killers but we don't like them to be sadists at all. This needs more clarification.

Comment: This is asking for us to develop a plot device for your story. That is story-based and thus off-topic for this site. I am voting to close.

Comment: Isn't path-from-good-to-evil the whole story of the Star Wars #2 and #3? And a whole bunch of Shakespeare?

Comment: Pride will bring down the very best of us.  You just have to be subtle about it.

Comment: @swswsws **Religion**. Religion is the notion that there exists a morality and a set of ethics that are above and beyond that of humans. That there is an ultimate and **final** rule-book that states "Right & Wrong", one that is better and more pure than that what puny humans can come up with. With religion you can set aside **any and all human morality**. As stated by [Steven Weinberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Weinberg#Religion): *"With or without religion, good people can behave well and bad people can do evil; but for good people to do evil—that takes religion."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradually. War is an excellent source of sadistic behaviours. To start with, normal rules about killing or destroying property are somewhat in suspension - same for robbery. Then, you are under constant pressure and fear for your life and that of your comrades, friends and family - either they are in the front line with you or not.

In war, there's no rules, and if the enemy does something sadistic, cruel and *effective* you have to resort to something which is as effective as that, or better, which usually amounts to do the same thing, or a thing that is going to be as cruel and sadistic as its means or worse.

When people is exposed to that level of violence they loose their sensitivity to it - or go mad. We punish a crime with a certain sensation of proportionality to the offense commited, but when we live a life where death is so cheap, when we have seen so many people and friend dying from bullets, just putting a bullet through the head of the man who has raped your sister doesn't feel nearly enough of a punishment. After all, being killed by a bullet is something that you have seen too many times, and even desire for yourself (rather than being burnt alive like you have seen some comrades die). So you go for a slower, more painful way to kill him.

That's how monsters are raised. Step by step.